# Transporting monitors

Tags: display

I am moving two flat screen monitors (one 19" and the other 17") 300 miles to my university flat. The car will be full of other items, so I can't do what I normally do which is to lay them on the back seats. The main concern I had was that they didn't get damaged (scratched) in transport.

My current idea is to wrap them in a duvet and then put the duvet in a binbag. Is that overkill or does anyone have any better suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The *best* way to transport them is in the original packaging. Failing that, your method is acceptable provided nothing can strike the large surface.

Answer (score 1):

- If possible move them in their **original packaging**
- If you don't have the original then you may put a **thick blanket** or a **piece of cardboard** (tape it to their sides) on the screen and move them in some box
- Try to fill the empty space in box with **thermocol** if possible